# How to fix my Discord bots command, !setgame

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm developing a python discord bot, and I'd love for anyone to help me with this problem i cannot seem to get around

anyways, I made the command !setgame game here, but when i do for instance
!setgame message user# for help it doesnt work how it should, it only uses one line of the game message so if i say !setgame 1 2 3 it would only use 1 not 2 or 3

Here's the code:

```
    async def cmd_setgame(self, text):
        game = discord.Game(name="%s"% text)
        await self.change_status(game)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g720dw mate they already are indented im seriously not sure why its not working

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g7216u heres what the command does

Comment: Your problem is on a wider scope. The function itself is fine, but where it is called is where `text` is only being passed 1 and not 2 3. Are you using ext?

Comment: nope im not using ext what should be done to get it

Comment: If you dont use it, thats fine. Can you please give some surrounding context. Like I said before your function is fine, its the function that calls it that has an issue with it. Basically, something is only passing 1 into `text` instead of 1 2 3.

Answer (score -1):

From http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-do-my-arguments-require-quotes:

```
async def cmd_setgame(self, *, text):
    game = discord.Game(name="%s"% text)
    await self.change_status(game)
```

Comment: Check the comments above, apparently OP doesn't use ext, so this would not work...